# Rails instagram error: {"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I am having a scenario where users can upload pictures through Instagram.

This is my controller callback method:

```
def instagram_callback
    response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => Rails.application.config.custom.domain_url + 'instagram/callback/?edit=' + (params[:edit].present? ? params[:edit] : ''))
    oauth = OauthAccessToken.find_or_create_by(provider:'instagram', user_id:current_user.id)
    oauth.access_token = response.access_token
    oauth.save
    if params[:edit].present?
      redirect_to edit_user_report_path(current_user, params[:edit], :ig => true)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_report_path(current_user, :ig => true)
    end
  end
```

In my instagram.rb, I am having all the credentials(using sandbox).

When I run the code, it asking instagram login, when I login with my insta account(sandbox credentials are given from this account), it is working fine but when I try to login with another account, it is throwing account as:

> {"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException",
>   "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}

This is my url:

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/instagram/callback/?edit=&response_type=code
```

Please help.

Comment: @ sachin god:-
Do you solve this?

Comment: @Jayshree Kind of late, but I ended up solving this by unchecking 'Disable Implicit OAuth' in my client settings. This will make it work but I am unhappy with the solution since it seems less secure.